# How to send img path from static folder using localhost using Python and Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Python and Flask. I am facing issue trying serve an image:

I have image stored in the `static` folder and I need to send  image path as json response, so that the users can see the image. I have tried `os.path.abspath()`, and it's giving me full path but still the image is not accessible using that path with localhost in the browser. The solution should also be usable with mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `url_for` combined with your hostname, or localhost if you just want to see it yourself.

For example:

```py
"localhost"+url_for('static', filename='image.png')
```

From [The Flask quickstart quide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#url-building):

> To build a URL to a specific function you can use the url_for() function. It accepts the name of the function as first argument and a number of keyword arguments, each corresponding to the variable part of the URL rule.

About [static files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#static-files):

> ## Static Files
>
> Dynamic web applications also need static files. That’s usually where the  CSS and JavaScript files are coming from. Ideally your web server is configured to serve them for you, but during development Flask can do that as well. Just create a folder called static in your package or next to your module and it will be available at /static on the application.
>
> To generate URLs for static files, use the special 'static' endpoint name:
>
> url_for('static', filename='style.css')
>   The file has to be stored on the filesystem as static/style.css.

If you have static IP and port open to external network, don't forget to use `0.0.0.0` as your hostname if you are trying to make your page visible to others too. You might also want to use a separate web server, as suggested in the Flask docs.

Comment: thanks.. But my image is in static/upload folder and url_for() is throwing error when I am giving like this url_for('static/upload', filename='image.png')